# Unable to get participant availablility for the meetings status scheduled between 00:00 to 05:30 EWS API java

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.valueOf(version));    
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(userName, password, domain);           
service.setCredentials(credentials);
service.setUrl(new URI(url));
service.setTraceEnabled(true);
List<AttendeeInfo> attendees = new ArrayList<AttendeeInfo>();
attendees.add(new AttendeeInfo(mailId));
//StartDate = Sat Dec 03 00:00:00 IST 2016 & endDate=Sat Dec 04 00:00:00 IST          2016
GetUserAvailabilityResults results = service.getUserAvailability(attendees, new TimeWindow(startDate, endDate), AvailabilityData.FreeBusy);
for (AttendeeAvailability attendeeAvailability : results.getAttendeesAvailability()) {
    for (CalendarEvent calendarEvent : attendeeAvailability.getCalendarEvents()) {
        System.out.println("StartTime>>>" + calendarEvent.getStartTime() + ", EndTime>>>"   + calendarEvent.getEndTime());

    }
}
```

Am unable to get availability status for the meetings scheduled between 00:00 AM & 05:30 AM IST. However am able to get availability for meetings scheduled somewhere after 05:30 AM

Thanks in advance!!